Vurforia marker tracking at the wrong position after few uses in Hololens 2
I have hololens 2 (using unity for app building) and use it for tracking a marker and get the position in the hololens but after few times or few app restarting, vuforia still tracks the marker but the position it gives is wrong.
I am currently trying to find a way to place the marker position manually but I am afraid I am not succeed at all.
I am pretty confused what is causing the issue here. Is hololens changing it's world origin point after some uses or vuforia is sending wrong information.
I want the marker position to stay right on where marker get's tracked.

Is the Vuforia result marked as Limited/Extended Tracked? If this is the case it is possible that Vuforia is reporting some stale data from a previous run.

It is set to extended tracked. I have tried 'Tracked' but it is not required as I need the marker to stay tracked if it's little hidden. @emay

In general only when it is "Tracked" you have a reasonable guarantee that the object is well aligned. In extended tracking mode Engine is reporting the last known position propagated according to the DeviceTracker information. If the Hololens device tracker reports the wrong pose then also the extended tracked pose for your target will be incorrect. You could implement some custom logic that on app restart you ignore extended tracked poses but you used them if they immediately follow a "tracked" pose.
